# Fetch multiple fields at once

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

Currently my query looks like that

```
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT `body` FROM `messages` WHERE `id`=? AND `status'='success');
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $msgid);
    $rc = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($message);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
```

Let's say, `$msgid` is array (1, 2, 5, 7). Is it possible to fetch all `body`, `status` fields where id is 1, 2, 5, 7  at once and merge all `body`'s to one variable seperated by whitespace? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: You mean something like `... WHERE id IN(1, 2, 5, 7)`?

Comment: @Quasdunk yes. Lets say `body` for `id 1` is `sample1`. For `id 2` is `sample2` .. so on. I want to get `sample1 sample2` in one variable

Comment: I've got a question. while it is possible to merge all body's to one string, what about status? what form it have to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) - The following code should do what you need with PDO.

```
$values = array(1, 2, 5, 7);
$parameters = implode(',', str_split(str_repeat('?', count($values)));

$stmt = $this->db->prepare("
  SELECT 
      GROUP_CONCAT(body SEPARATOR ' ') as gbody 
    FROM 
      messages 
    WHERE 
      id IN($parameters) 
      AND status='success'
");
$stmt->execute($values);
$res = $stmt->fetch();
echo $res['gbody'];
$stmt->close();
```

Comment: `$valueCount = implode(',',array_fill(0,count($values),'?'));` ;-)

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: Why would that array_fill help? :)

Comment: it will save you 4 lines. Four because in your current code you have to add `$valueCount = '';` before loop. So, with array_fill it would be one line instead of 5.

Answer (score 2):

no, there is no placeholder for IN statement. 
you have to write a simple program which have to produce `(?,?,?)` string to be added to the query and then bind your array to this query.

well, it turned out to be a **four** questions at once:

1. How to query a database for multiple conditions
2. How to build such a query using prepared statements
3. How to fetch multiple rows
4. How to fetch multiple fields in one

However it seems that you need not the short answer but the book (or, rather, two - basic PHP and basic mysql one), here are answers for your reference

1. use IN statement. SQL statement `WHERE id IN(1, 2, 5, 7)` will query the database for all the id.
2. As I wrote above, create a small program to produce `(?,?,?)` statement, with number of `?` matching number of array elements. Than bind it usual way.
3. A manual page for the execute() does contain an example on fetching multiple rows, I believe. I am always refer to manual for the examples myself.
4. SQL function group_concat() can do it. `select group_concat(body SEPARATOR ' ')` will select all your bodies in one row

Comment: Is it possible to fetch all table as array then, get exact rows one by one?

Comment: this question is qite irrelevant. Your database API lets you fetch multiple rows for sure. Are you sure you have no idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is possible with parameters, but it's easy with built SQL:

```
$imp=implode(',',$msgid);
"SELECT `body`, `status` FROM `messages` WHERE `id` IN (0$imp)"
```

The 0 after the opening bracket helps you over the hurdle of $msgid being an empty array.

This assumes is_numeric($msgid[$i]) is true for all valid $i, or you lose your database ...

Comment: Actually READING the first line of my answer would show you, that my solution can't use parameters. So editing your code is not an option. Downvoting for being too lazy to read is rude.